# Sequence of Logic in Diffusion Problem DQ

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, applications

Problem: If a tank is filled with 100 gallons of water and mistakenly added 300 pounds of salt. To fix the mistake the brine is drained at 3 gallons per minute and replaced with water at the same rate. Assuming that the sodium is spread equally, how long will it take for the salt to be 200 pounds?

Difficulty: Logically, we can create the following equation:

$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{3x}{100}$

What I don't comprehend is why $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ is then substituted as $\frac{dx}{dt}$ to be solved. This also begs the question of how a *derivable* set of differential equations are recognized when the data given isn't instantaneous. From how it's presented in DQ texts, it suggests that these differential equations come from the data, but to me, it seems to come from knowing phenomena that mimic general functions like exponential decay and growth models. And working that into problem-solving.

For example, if given a set of data and recognizing that it follows an exponential growth pattern and that most reduce to the form
$\frac{dN}{dt}=k$, then we solve. But it's not clear that the phenomenon suggests this DQ on the basis of the rate of change and knowledge on the definition of derivative.

Comment: ‘Raises the question’ maybe, ‘begging the question’ is something quite different.